# django foreignKey refer to more than one table

Tags: django, python-3.x

I had two models. Parents and Children. Because Children and Parents have some different fields I had to separate them instead of having a single model person.
And because a child should have a father and a mother I had two separate fathers and mothers in separate models.
So far:

```
 class Father(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...
 class Mother(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...
 class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...
    father=models.ForeignKey(Father)
    mother...
```

It should be better designed but I am not a pro.

Now I need to have another model for health. Is it possible to have a model which fields belongs to a child or a father or a mother? Or I should make one health model for each like childhealth, fatherhealth etc?
thnx in advance

Comment: take a look at [django generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations), may be it can help you

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use `GenericForeignKey` in this situation. What it is and how to use it you can find out from the documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.10/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#module-django.contrib.contenttypes

Comment: For who downvoting. The question was `Is it possible to have a model which fields belongs to a child or a father or a mother? Or I should make one health model for each like childhealth, fatherhealth etc?`

Answer (score 1):

You can create abstract model, e.g. `HumanAbstract`

```
class HumanAbstract(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    rest_common_fields = ...
```

And then your `Father`, `Mother`, `Child` can be inherited from `HumanAbstract`. Since in `Meta` `HumanAbstract` have `abstract = True` it won't be created in database.

[**Docs**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) about abstract classes.

Also you can eliminate `Father` and `Mother` models, and create only `Parent` model.

```
class Parent(HumanAbstract):
    pass

class Child(HumanAbstract):
    father = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    mother = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    ...
```

**UPDATE**

@SergeyZherevchuk is right about `GenericForeignKey`, you can simply integrate that and it would be the best choice.

```
class HealthModel(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    ...
```